# how to install Matplotlib on Cygwin?

Tags: python, cygwin, matplotlib

I'm trying to install Matplotlib 1.0.1 version on latest Cygwin. In the processing, there is a weird fork error cannot be solved. I googled similar questions and found that it might be solved by manually running gcc/g++ with matplotlib 0.98.5.2 : http://innuendopoly.org/arch/matplotlib-cygwin. But it doesn't work under 1.0.1 version. Does anybody encounter the same problem?

Answer (score 13):

Here are instructions for how to install matplotlib 1.1.0 on Cygwin

http://berlinbrowndev.blogspot.com/2012/01/python-matplotlib-plotting-setup-for.html

## Python matplotlib plotting setup for cygwin

Matplotlib is a popular python library for generating plot graphics.   It works with cygwin win32 but some non-intuitive steps are required.

### Install cygwin:

```
CYGWIN_NT-5.1 1.7.9(0.237/5/3) 2011-03-29 10:10 i686 Cygwin
```

I am using cygwin with setup 2.7.3

### Install python through cygwin:

This document describes installing python and matplot with cygwin.  For most windows users and cygwin users, normally you would use the external python executable.  I tend to prefer all of my script oriented applications running through cygwin including python.

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Jun 12 2010, 17:07:01)
[GCC 4.3.4 20090804 (release) 1] on cygwin
```

In the cygwin setup.exe installer, install:

- The freetype libs, python-gtk, python-tk, libpng
- gcc

### Download matplotlib from sourceforge:

I am using the latest version matplotlib-1.1.0 as of 1/2012.

Download and extract the matplotlib tarball

### Issues with standard python install and cygwin:

The typical 'python setup.py install' will not work with cygwin.  You need to modify a configuration file and run some other additional commands.

In the root directory of the expanded matplotlib directory, copy the setup.cfg.template configuration file to setup.cfg.  Edit setup.cfg.

Around line 70 in the file is a commented line, uncomment the line such that you have:

```
tkagg = False
```

### Run install and watch it fail

Try running 'python setup.py install'

It should fail with an error like the following:

```
2 [main] python 2796 C:\cygwin\bin\python.exe: *** fatal error - unable to remap C:\cygwin\bin\cyggfortran-3.dll to same address as parent: 0x18660000 != 0x69780000
Stack trace:
```

### Run the rebase command OUTSIDE OF THE TYPICAL CYGWIN ENV

Exit cygwin and close all cygwin instances including the one you are working with.  You won't be using the typical  cygwin prompt for the next command.

In windows explorer, open the cmd.exe or windows command

You will need to run rebaseall.  First, shut down any long running processes like sshd, close all Cygwin prompts and so on.

Type the following commands:

```
cd \cygwin\bin
ash
PATH=. rebaseall -v

...
```

And you should get several lines of output.

### Run install and watch it succeed

Try running 'python setup.py install' command again in the matplotlib directory

### Running Example Program:

```
# python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Jun 12 2010, 17:07:01)
[GCC 4.3.4 20090804 (release) 1] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
pyplot.pie([1,2,3])
pyplot.show()
pyplot.savefig('f.png')
pyplot.savefig('x.eps')
```

Comment: Thank you!

I tried it today and it worked seamlessly, it didn't even fail the first time. I guess someone fixed something since January.

Comment: The following required packages can not be built: freetype - that is what it tells me after all. Does not work. Where can I get working freetype for 64bit?

Comment: Launch the Cygwin setup (in my case setup-x86_64.exe) and in the package list search for freetype2, select all found packages to install. You also need pkg-config so that dependency packages are detected automatically. Do the same, search for pkg-config and select all found packages to install. That's it. I didn't have any errors while compiling and installing, only some warnings but that should be ok. I installed it with: python setup.py install. If you just want to check for dependency errors do just: python setup.py

Comment: May I ask, why should disable `tkagg`?

Comment: Now with a recent version of cygwin it's not necessary anymore to disable tkagg.'python setup.py install' works.

Answer (score 6):

These steps taken from [www.scivision.co](https://www.scivision.co/matplotlib-in-cygwin-64-bit/) worked for me:

1. Run Cygwin setup: (For some reason the original command posted in the source link did not work for me)
2. install packages: (most of these you may already have)

   - pkg-config
   - ghostscript
   - libfreetype-devel
   - libpng-devel
   - libgtk2.0-devel
   - gcc-g++
   - git
   - openbox
   - python3-numpy
   - python3-pyqt5
   - python3-devel
3. Then from Cygwin Terminal:

`easy_install-3.6 pip
    pip install --upgrade six
    pip install matplotlib`

4. Then tested from python console:

`import matplotlib
    matplotlib.__version__`

Comment: Thanks, still works in 2019.  See comment by @FelisKastner below too.  I did not have to upgrade `six`, just after a cygwin default update.

Comment: After a complete new Cygwin install, I also had to install libcrypt-devel, and python36-pyqty5 (there was no python3-pyqt5).  An attempt to include python3.7 (and using the corresponding easy_install) failed at `pip install matplotlib`, a gcc compile failure, with an error log over 10,000 lines so I couldn't see what started it (the rest were failures to handle the failure.)

Answer (score 1):

Installation worked for me as described by Felix above.
But to use matplotlib you need to start the Xserver from Cygwin first:

```
startxwin
```

and then start your script.

Comment: Thanks!  I also had to run cygserver to avoid shmem() and other errors. https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygserver.html#start-cygserver .  And of course, set DISPLAY variable.  (And run startxwin in the background.)