# Installing freetype (pre-requisite for matplotlib) on Cygwin: mission impossible?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cygwin, freetype, freetype2

I fail to install `freetype` (a *pre-requisite* for `matplotlib)` on `Cygwin,`  eventhough I followed the instructions on [freetype2.html](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/freetype2.html), and did all the suggestions - on the first few page worth of results - of this [Google search](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22the%20following%20required%20packages%20can%20not%20be%20built%22%20freetype%20cygwin), especially this [stack-overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151755/how-to-install-matplotlib-on-cygwin/9013184#9013184).

### Can anyone detail their success in installing `freetype/matplotlib` on `Cygwin`?

---

**My Setup:**

- Cygwin 1.7.35(0.287/5/3) i686
- [image: Windows 7]

**What I did?**

- On Cygwin's setup (setup-x86.exe) I entered `freetype` and `pkg-config,` and installed all found packages (and their dependencies).
- Then:

  `$ apt-cyg search freetype
  Searching downloaded packages...
  cygwin64-freetype2
  girepository-x11
  libfontconfig-devel
  libfreetype-devel
  libfreetype-doc
  libfreetype6`
- and:

  `$ for i in cygwin64-freetype2 girepository-x11 libfontconfig-devel libfreetype-devel libfreetype-doc libfreetype6 ; do echo "$i" ; apt-cyg install $i ; done`

  `cygwin64-freetype2
  Package cygwin64-freetype2 is already installed, skipping
  girepository-x11
  Package girepository-x11 is already installed, skipping
  libfontconfig-devel
  Package libfontconfig-devel is already installed, skipping
  libfreetype-devel
  Package libfreetype-devel is already installed, skipping
  libfreetype-doc
  Package libfreetype-doc is already installed, skipping
  libfreetype6
  Package libfreetype6 is already installed, skipping`

  `$ apt-cyg install pkg-config
  Package pkg-config is already installed, skipping`
- Verifying:

  `$ freetype-config --version
  17.4.11`
- So, it seems that freetype is installed in my Cygwin.
- ***Alas:***

  `$ easy_install matplotlib
  Searching for matplotlib
  Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/
  Reading http://matplotlib.org
  Reading http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net
  Reading http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706
  Reading http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=82474
  Reading http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.1.0/
  Reading http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.1.1/
  Reading https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=278194
  Reading https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=82474
  Reading https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-0.99.1/
  Reading https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-0.99.3/
  Reading https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.0
  Reading https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.0.1/
  Best match: matplotlib 1.4.3
  Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.3.tar.gz#md5=86af2e3e3c61849ac7576a6f5ca44267
  Processing matplotlib-1.4.3.tar.gz
  Writing /cygdrive/c/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/easy_install-D6sdBX/matplotlib-1.4.3/setup.cfg
  Running matplotlib-1.4.3/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /cygdrive/c/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/easy_install-D6sdBX/matplotlib-1.4.3/egg-dist-tmp-q6Vh0z
  IMPORTANT WARNING:
      pkg-config is not installed.
      matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies`
  `===========================================================================
  Edit setup.cfg to change the build options`

  `BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
              matplotlib: yes [1.4.3]
                  python: yes [2.7.8 (default, Jul 28 2014, 01:34:03)  [GCC
                          4.8.3]]
                platform: yes [cygwin]`

  `REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                   numpy: yes [version 1.9.2]
                     six: yes [using six version 1.9.0]
                dateutil: yes [dateutil was not found. It is required for date
                          axis support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                          install it after matplotlib.]
                    pytz: yes [using pytz version 2015.2]
                 tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                          WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                          install it after matplotlib.]
               pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for
                          mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                          install it after matplotlib.]
                   pycxx: yes [Couldn't import.  Using local copy.]
                  libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                          be found. Using local copy.]
                freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype2 (ft2build.h)
                          could not be found.  You may need to install the
                          development package.]
                     png: yes [version 1.6.17]
                   qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be
                          found. Using local copy.]`

  `OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
             sample_data: yes [installing]
                toolkits: yes [installing]
                   tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
                          matplotlib test suite.  pip/easy_install may attempt
                          to install it after matplotlib. / mock is required
                          to run the matplotlib test suite.  pip/easy_install
                          may attempt to install it after matplotlib.]
          toolkits_tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
                          matplotlib test suite.  pip/easy_install may attempt
                          to install it after matplotlib. / mock is required
                          to run the matplotlib test suite.  pip/easy_install
                          may attempt to install it after matplotlib.]`

  `OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                  macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                  qt5agg: yes [installing, Qt: 5.3.2, PyQt: 5.3.2]
                  qt4agg: yes [installing, Qt: 4.8.6, PyQt: 4.8.6]
                  pyside: no  [PySide not found]
                 gtk3agg: no  [Requires gtk3 development files to be
                          installed.]
               gtk3cairo: no  [Requires gtk3 development files to be
                          installed.]
  /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
    warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
                  gtkagg: no  [The C/C++ header for gtk (gtk/gtk.h) could not
                          be found.  You may need to install the development
                          package.]
                   tkagg: yes [installing, version 81008]
                   wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                     gtk: no  [The C/C++ header for gtk (gtk/gtk.h) could not
                          be found.  You may need to install the development
                          package.]
                     agg: yes [installing]
                   cairo: yes [installing, pycairo version 1.10.0]
               windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]`

  `OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                  dvipng: yes [version 1.14]
             ghostscript: yes [version 9.15]
                   latex: yes [version 3.14159265]
                 pdftops: no`
  `===========================================================================
                          * The following required packages can not be built:
                          * freetype`

**So, despite my false hope, freetype cannot be built and thus - matplotlib cannot be installed.**

Comment: I don't understand. About half-way through, you determine that freetype not only _can_ be built and installed, but already _has_ been built and installed. And then, at the end, you claim that it _can't_ be built? That can't be right. Is the problem that matplotlib can't _find_ freetype, and therefore can't build _its freetype wrapper module_?

Comment: If that is your problem, there are a few bugs on matplotlib that sound relevant. [This one](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3029/) also links to the two others I found in a quick search, and also links to an SO question. Have you read all of those? (I don't know if any of them are relevant, they just look like they might be…)

Comment: @abarnert, regarding your first comment: indeed, seems freetype is installed correctly, but matplotlib does not concur. Regarding your second comment: yes, I read these bugs (they were included in the Goggle search I mentioned).

Comment: Well, my Windows VM is out of disk space, so I think I'm done here, but maybe someone else can help. I would strongly suggest rewording the title and the introduction so that they make it clear that your problem is building matplotlib with freetype support, not building freetype, and if you can find a way to make this shorter (even just moving the log into a big code block so it scrolls within the main entry would help) it might attract more eyes.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/jbmohler/matplotlib-winbuild ?

Comment: And the problem is that (for what ever reason) the header files are not being found is your include path.  Try adding setting the path that they exist at into the env INCLUDE

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @ tcaswell, but - I'm quite sure that instructions for installing `matplotlib` on _Windows_ (e.g., requiring _Visual Studio_) don't apply to *Cygwin*. Moreover, the headers you mention are for _optional_ components.